# Dealing with input images of different shapes in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I've started to work with a [leaf classification dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/leaf-classification) on Kaggle. All input images have different rectangular shapes. I want to transform the input into squares of a fixed size (say, 224x224) with a symmetric zero-padding either on top and bottom or on the left and right sides of the rectangle. Prior to that, I think that I need to rescale the image (some images in the dataset have shapes `>1000`). I've encountered the next two problems:

1. `torchvision.transforms.Resize(size)` rescales the image so that its smaller side is matched to `size` (`size` is a scalar). I want the opposite, the bigger side to be matched to `size`.
2. `torchvision.transforms.Pad(padding)` seemingly works only with some fixed `padding`, but this transform will not always output a square.

How would you resolve this problem? I'm aware of `RandomSizedCrop`, but I feel like some datasets (like this one) aren't good for this method (some of the input images are too oblong). Also, I heard that `RandomSizedCrop` shouldn't be 
used for the test data loaders.

More generally, how do you deal with input images of different rectangular shapes in PyTorch? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've found some good answers on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44231209/resize-rectangular-image-to-square-keeping-ratio-and-fill-background-with-black/44231784)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function that uses cv2 resize function:

```
def leaf_image(image_id,target_length=160):
    """
    `image_id` should be the index of the image in the images/ folder

    Reture the image of a given id(1~1584) with the target size (target_length x target_length)

    """

    image_name = str(image_id) + '.jpg'
    leaf_img = plt.imread('images/'+image_name)  # Reading in the image 
    leaf_img_width = leaf_img.shape[1]
    leaf_img_height = leaf_img.shape[0]
    #target_length = 160
    img_target = np.zeros((target_length, target_length), np.uint8)
    if leaf_img_width >= leaf_img_height:
        scale_img_width = target_length
        scale_img_height = int( (float(scale_img_width)/leaf_img_width)*leaf_img_height )
        img_scaled = cv2.resize(leaf_img, (scale_img_width, scale_img_height), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        copy_location = (target_length-scale_img_height)/2
        img_target[copy_location:copy_location+scale_img_height,:] = img_scaled
    else:
        # leaf_img_width < leaf_img_height:
        scale_img_height = target_length
        scale_img_width = int( (float(scale_img_height)/leaf_img_height)*leaf_img_width )
        img_scaled = cv2.resize(leaf_img, (scale_img_width, scale_img_height), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        copy_location = (target_length-scale_img_width)/2
        img_target[:, copy_location:copy_location+scale_img_width] = img_scaled 

    return img_target


# Test the leaf_image function
leaf_id = 343
leaf_img = leaf_image(leaf_id, target_length=160); 

plt.imshow(leaf_img, cmap='gray'); plt.title('Leaf # '+str(leaf_id)); plt.axis('off'); plt.show()
```

Source: https://github.com/WenjinTao/Leaf-Classification--Kaggle/blob/master/Leaf_Classification_using_Machine_Learning.ipynb